# Is there a regex function for kubernetes helm templates available?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to implement an ingress helm template encoding the current application version into the url. This shall allow users to do soft migration by providing them different versions of the application.

Example:

```
mydomain.org/1.0/applicationpath
mydomain.org/1.1/applicationpath
mydomain.org/2.0/applicationpath
```

To prevent configuring this manually in the ingress on each update, I would prefer a regex determining the major.minor version automatically.
The application is revised according to Semver 2.0.0, so a pattern like \d+.\d+ should do the work.

I tried something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: {{ .Release.Name }}-my-srv
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.app.ingress.host }}
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /{{ .Chart.AppVersion | regex \d+.\d+ }}
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find a function for regular expressions.
Is there an option to achieve this with a helm template?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is. However it is unfortunately undocumented.
Helm uses the [sprig](https://godoc.org/github.com/Masterminds/sprig) library to provide additional functions for templating. What is undocumented is many of the sprig functions that have been added to the code (ref [issue #84](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/issues/84)), and the regex functions are some of them. You can find these functions here: https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/regex.go

Thus you can do `{{ .Chart.AppVersion | regexFind "\d+\.\d+" }}`

<sup>*(note that I also added a `\` before the `.` to escape it as `.` means to match any character, which does not seem to be your intent)*</sup>

Not your use case, but one item of note for others which might be interested in using the `regex*` functions from sprig, is that unfortunately the sprig owner made the subject string the second argument of all the functions, and some of the functions have additional arguments after it (e.g. the `regexReplaceAll` function). The reason why this is a problem is that when a function is used in a pipeline, the result of the previous element in the pipeline becomes the last argument of the function. So this does not work: `"foo subject string" | regexReplaceAll "foo" "bar"`, as it'll treat `bar` as the string to operate on, and `foo subject string` as the string to replace any occurrences of `foo` with (which in this example there would not be any).

Comment: Just in case anyone else has the same issue I did with this, I needed to escape the backslash in `\d` for this to work, making my template snippet `.Capabilities.KubeVersion.Minor | regexFind "\\d+"`

Comment: See also [issue #86](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/issues/86) which is about the awkward usage of regexReplaceAll* functions in pipelines.  You have to use `{{ "bar" | regexReplaceAll "foo" "foo subject string" }}` instead.

Answer (score 12):

Had to deal with this today, you will want something like:

`{{ regexFind "\\d+\\.\\d+" .Chart.AppVersion }}`

Requires the double escapes due to yaml.

[Docs for this](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/docs/strings.md#regexfind)